# How to count the number of commas in a string using regular expression in python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string in the following format:

```
str ="India,USA,Australia,Japan,Russia"
```

I want to extract the word present after third comma by counting the number of commas using regular expression in python.

desired output:`Japan`

Comment: What's wrong with using `s.split(",")[3]` instead?

Comment: actually I am reading multiple lines from .csv file. So it doesn't work while I read line by line: my code:                         for line1 in open('/home/prashant/Major_cities_final.csv', 'r') :
 result = line1.split(",")[2]
printresult     this does not give the required output

Comment: If you're reading a .csv file, use the csv module which understands the format properly (eg. quoted fields that contain commas).

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with a regular expression with something like

```
([^,]*,){3}([^,]*)
```

with the meaning

- `[^,]*` Zero or more chars but no commas
- `,` a comma
- `{3}` the previous group must be repeated three times
- `[^,]*` Zero or more chars but no commas

the second group will be the fourh comma-separated value

```
import re
text = "India,USA,Australia,Japan,Russia"
m = re.match("([^,]*,){3}([^,]*)", text)
if m:
    print m.group(2)
```

In this specific case however it would be much simpler to just split on commas and taking the fourth value:

```
print text.split(',')[3]
```